# How to identify the Debian branch of a package shown in the output of `apt-cache show <pkg>`?

Tags: debian, apt

I want to install packages from the Debian `testing` branch, like `tmux` and `git`.

Therefore, I have configured APT with `testing`, but to use `main` as the default:

```
nlykkei@debian-parallels ~ $ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/testing.list
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ testing main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ testing main
nlykkei@debian-parallels ~ $ cat /etc/apt/preferences.d/testing.pref
Package: *
Pin: release a=testing
Pin-Priority: 100
```

Now, when I check the `tmux` versions available, both `3.1-c1` and `2.8-3` versions show up. In this case, it's obvious that `3.1c-1` is from `testing`, but how can I identify that in a more complicated output?

I need the branch name for `apt-get install -t <branch> <pkg>...`, which sets `Pin-Priority: 990` for `<branch>`.

**`apt-cache show`**:

```
nlykkei@debian-parallels ~ $ apt-cache show tmux
Package: tmux
Version: 3.1c-1
Installed-Size: 830
Maintainer: Romain Francoise <rfrancoise@debian.org>
Architecture: amd64
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.27), libevent-2.1-7 (>= 2.1.8-stable), libtinfo6 (>= 6), libutempter0 (>= 1.1.5)
Description-en: terminal multiplexer
 tmux enables a number of terminals (or windows) to be accessed and
 controlled from a single terminal like screen. tmux runs as a
 server-client system. A server is created automatically when necessary
 and holds a number of sessions, each of which may have a number of
 windows linked to it. Any number of clients may connect to a session,
 or the server may be controlled by issuing commands with tmux.
 Communication takes place through a socket, by default placed in /tmp.
 Moreover tmux provides a consistent and well-documented command
 interface, with the same syntax whether used interactively, as a key
 binding, or from the shell. It offers a choice of vim or Emacs key
 layouts.
Description-md5: dc6ff920cb9183a42694d0ea54835078
Homepage: https://tmux.github.io/
Tag: hardware::input:keyboard, implemented-in::c, interface::text-mode,
 role::program, scope::application, works-with::software:running
Section: admin
Priority: optional
Filename: pool/main/t/tmux/tmux_3.1c-1_amd64.deb
Size: 362376
MD5sum: e0be6f85c58a244108eab29c9ee629cf
SHA256: 037f2f1f55c72e75e155cb54cdd9c41f4ac7575cef50a1427383b043cc8316e0

Package: tmux
Version: 2.8-3
Installed-Size: 681
Maintainer: Romain Francoise <rfrancoise@debian.org>
Architecture: amd64
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.27), libevent-2.1-6 (>= 2.1.8-stable), libtinfo6 (>= 6), libutempter0 (>= 1.1.5)
Description-en: terminal multiplexer
 tmux enables a number of terminals (or windows) to be accessed and
 controlled from a single terminal like screen. tmux runs as a
 server-client system. A server is created automatically when necessary
 and holds a number of sessions, each of which may have a number of
 windows linked to it. Any number of clients may connect to a session,
 or the server may be controlled by issuing commands with tmux.
 Communication takes place through a socket, by default placed in /tmp.
 Moreover tmux provides a consistent and well-documented command
 interface, with the same syntax whether used interactively, as a key
 binding, or from the shell. It offers a choice of vim or Emacs key
 layouts.
Description-md5: dc6ff920cb9183a42694d0ea54835078
Homepage: https://tmux.github.io/
Tag: hardware::input:keyboard, implemented-in::c, interface::text-mode,
 role::program, scope::application, works-with::software:running
Section: admin
Priority: optional
Filename: pool/main/t/tmux/tmux_2.8-3_amd64.deb
Size: 302084
MD5sum: 17d694a86ec7b0f46ac6ff60e0d843ff
SHA256: 9c247aef3c3c09d982d49a14091209d76bd06a3d2e699fc9d60ddcee203b456a
```

**`apt-cache policy`**:

```
nlykkei@debian-parallels ~ $ apt-cache policy
Package files:
 100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     release a=now
 100 http://deb.debian.org/debian testing/main amd64 Packages
     release o=Debian,a=testing,n=bullseye,l=Debian,c=main,b=amd64
     origin deb.debian.org
 500 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates/main amd64 Packages
     release o=Debian,a=stable-updates,n=buster-updates,l=Debian,c=main,b=amd64
     origin deb.debian.org
 500 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates/main amd64 Packages
     release v=10,o=Debian,a=stable,n=buster,l=Debian-Security,c=main,b=amd64
     origin security.debian.org
 500 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 Packages
     release v=10.9,o=Debian,a=stable,n=buster,l=Debian,c=main,b=amd64
     origin deb.debian.org
Pinned packages:
```

**Update**:

```
tmux:
  Installed: 3.1c-1~bpo10+1
  Candidate: 3.1c-1~bpo10+1
  Version table:
 *** 3.1c-1~bpo10+1 100
        100 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.8-3 990
        990 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 Packages
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`apt-cache show` won’t tell you which “branch” it is describing, but `apt show` will:

```
$ apt show -a tmux
Package: tmux
Version: 3.1c-1
Priority: optional
Section: admin
Maintainer: Romain Francoise <rfrancoise@debian.org>
Installed-Size: 850 kB
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.27), libevent-2.1-7 (>= 2.1.8-stable), libtinfo6 (>= 6), libutempter0 (>= 1.1.5)
Homepage: https://tmux.github.io/
Tag: hardware::input:keyboard, implemented-in::c, interface::text-mode,
 role::program, scope::application, works-with::software:running
Download-Size: 362 kB
APT-Sources: http://deb.debian.org/debian testing/main amd64 Packages
Description: terminal multiplexer
 tmux enables a number of terminals (or windows) to be accessed and
 controlled from a single terminal like screen. tmux runs as a
 server-client system. A server is created automatically when necessary
 and holds a number of sessions, each of which may have a number of
 windows linked to it. Any number of clients may connect to a session,
 or the server may be controlled by issuing commands with tmux.
 Communication takes place through a socket, by default placed in /tmp.
 Moreover tmux provides a consistent and well-documented command
 interface, with the same syntax whether used interactively, as a key
 binding, or from the shell. It offers a choice of vim or Emacs key
 layouts.

Package: tmux
Version: 2.8-3
Priority: optional
Section: admin
Maintainer: Romain Francoise <rfrancoise@debian.org>
Installed-Size: 697 kB
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.27), libevent-2.1-6 (>= 2.1.8-stable), libtinfo6 (>= 6), libutempter0 (>= 1.1.5)
Homepage: https://tmux.github.io/
Tag: hardware::input:keyboard, implemented-in::c, interface::text-mode,
 role::program, scope::application, works-with::software:running
Download-Size: 302 kB
APT-Manual-Installed: yes
APT-Sources: http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 Packages
Description: terminal multiplexer
 tmux enables a number of terminals (or windows) to be accessed and
 controlled from a single terminal like screen. tmux runs as a
 server-client system. A server is created automatically when necessary
 and holds a number of sessions, each of which may have a number of
 windows linked to it. Any number of clients may connect to a session,
 or the server may be controlled by issuing commands with tmux.
 Communication takes place through a socket, by default placed in /tmp.
 Moreover tmux provides a consistent and well-documented command
 interface, with the same syntax whether used interactively, as a key
 binding, or from the shell. It offers a choice of vim or Emacs key
 layouts.
```

Look for the `APT-Sources` lines: they indicate which repository the information corresponds to.

Comment: Thank you. Personally, I think it's a bit of a clutter that `apt show` is needed here, just like `apt list --installed` is needed to list installed packages. The addition of `apt` really makes things more complicated, since one cannot center on using `apt-cache` and `apt-get`, etc.

Comment: Will you comment on whether my approach of installing single packages from `testing` branch is correct? I have already messed up one system by doing `apt-get upgrade` after having simply added `testing` to `sources.list` without a preference

Comment: The general idea is that you can just use `apt`, instead of having to remember whether you need `apt-get` or `apt-cache`. As far as using `testing` with `stable`, I tend to think it’s a bad idea, but your pins seem OK; it’s up to you now to always keep an eye on what `apt upgrade` is going to do before letting it go ahead.

Comment: What is the alternative to using `testing` with `stable`? `git` and `tmux` package versions are **very** old in `main`, and so essential functionality is missing.

Comment: They’re both available in Buster backports, you should use that instead.

Comment: Thanks. Buster backports is a much cleaner solution. Do you know why using Buster backports has added another entry in `apt show -a <pkg>` for `APT-Sources: /var/lib/dpkg/status`?

Answer (score 1):

You almost had it with `apt-cache policy`.  You just needed to append a package name to that command line.

You can use `apt-cache policy [package...]` to show which version is installed, the default installation candidate version, and all versions available to be installed (according to your `sources.list` file(s) and pinning configuration or `APT::Default-Release` setting).

For example, on one of my systems that is configured to use `sid` aka `unstable` by default (due to the `APT::Default-Release "unstable";` line in my `/etc/apt/apt.conf`), and also allow cherry-picking packages from `experimental`:

```
$ apt-cache policy tmux
tmux:
  Installed: 3.1c-1
  Candidate: 3.1c-1
  Version table:
     3.2~rc4-1 1
          1 http://ftp.au.debian.org/debian experimental/main amd64 Packages
 *** 3.1c-1 990
        990 http://ftp.au.debian.org/debian unstable/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

"Installed" is the version currently installed.  "Candidate" is the version eligible to be installed according to your apt configuration (in this case, the candidate version is already installed).  "Version Table" shows all available versions.

Any other versions can be installed by specifying either the exact version number OR the target release that is defined in one of your `sources.list` file(s).  e.g. stable, testing, sid, experimental, or a the name of a specific debian release like "stretch" or "buster".

For example, one of the following:

```
apt install tmux=3.2~rc4-1

apt -t experimental install tmux

apt install tmux/experimental
```

BTW, you can also override the installation Candidate version shown by `apt-cache policy` by using the `-t target_release` option.  This is probably more useful in a script than as something you'd run from the command line, makes it easy to extract the candidate version with `grep -oP '^ +Candidate: \K.*'` or `awk -F': ' '/^ +Candidate:/ {print $2}'`.

Comment: Thanks. Why is the "Candidate" version, shown by `apt-cache policy tmux`, showing `Candidate: 3.1c-1` in my case, when I `stable` has a higher priority than `testing`?

Comment: @Shuzheng I don't know, I might be able to guess if you added the output of `apt-cache policy tmux` to your question.    Without that I can speculate that maybe apt handles pinning differently to just setting `APT::Default-Release` - aside from when gnome was going through it's transition from gnome 2 to gnome 3 (and i needed to pin the gnome packages to avoid getting gnome 3), I've never bothered with pinning, just setting the default release was good enough.  You can test that - does it behave differently if you have `APT::Default-Release "stable";` in /etc/apt/apt.conf?

Comment: Thanks. I have added the output of `apt policy tmux` with `APT::Default-Release "stable";` in `/etc/apt/apt.conf`. As you see, the candidate version is the one available from `buster-backports`, although those packages have a pinning of 100. It seems that even thus `buster` has a pinning of 990 that `buster-backports` `tmux` takes precedence, since that it's the currenly installed version.

Comment: It's probably because a pinning of 990, meaning *used as the default for the target release archive*, doesn't imply a downgrade (pinning 1001), and thus the `buster-backports` version is the candidate, since the version if newer than the `buster` version.